# ReactJS toggle button render twice

Tags: reactjs

I'd want to ask you a question about the toggle button.

So I just want to show the toggle button once. Consider this image.

[image]

When I try to make it, though, it displays twice.

[image]

Please help me in improving my code. Thank you very much.

My Code =

Button Component:

```js
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id={`toggle-${data.value}`}
    value={data.value}
    checked={data.value === value}
    onChange={() =>{
        if (data.value !== value) {
        onChange(data.value, data);
        }
    }}
    className={tw("hidden")}
    disabled={disabled || data.disabled || data.loading}
/>
```

full code button component : https://pastebin.com/YUEkpEDS

index : https://pastebin.com/n0md4rnu

Comment: Looks like you are iterating over elements in the "options" array. Does it have two elements?

Comment: The pastebin is no longer viewable. The problem is elsewhere.